# Find subgraphs that can only be reached by two nodes

Tags: graph, graph-theory, subgraph

I want to find subgraphs in a graph that are only connected to the rest of the graph by two nodes; for example, node A is connected to the rest of the graph, as well as node F, but nodes B-E are only connected to each other and A and F (don't have to be fully connected).
Is there a name for this? And is there an algorithm for finding such subgraphs?
The distance of A and F is defined by their shortest path: for example, if d=4, I would want to find all subgraphs where the shortest path between A-like and F-like nodes is at most 4.

Comment: The keyword is **3-connected maximal subgraphs**

Comment: You might have more success on https://cs.stackexchange.com